# Cant change variable with fast key presses

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create a game. Using key presses i want to change the direction of my player.

```
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    s.dir(0, -1);
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    s.dir(0, 1);
  } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    s.dir(1, 0);
  } else if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    s.dir(-1, 0);
  }
}
```

When i press on 2 keys too fast. I get these outputs:

> pressed 1 0 0 1
>
> pressed 0 1 -1 0

But in the second call, it cant seem to register that the input x is -1. And therefor the direction is not changed.

```
    this.dir = function(x, y) {
    console.log("pressed", this.xspeed, this.yspeed, x, y)
    if (y === -1) { // up
      if (this.y - scl != this.tail[this.tail.length-1].y) {
        this.xspeed = x;
        this.yspeed = y;
      }
    }
    if (y === 1) { // Down
      if (this.y + scl != this.tail[this.tail.length-1].y) {
        this.xspeed = x;
        this.yspeed = y;
      }
    }
    if (x === -1) { // Left
      if (this.x - scl != this.tail[this.tail.length-1].x) {
        this.xspeed = x;
        this.yspeed = y;
      }
    }
    if (x === 1) { // Right
      if (this.x + scl != this.tail[this.tail.length-1].x) {
        this.xspeed = x;
        this.yspeed = y;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can try setTimeout to simulate a delay between each keypress event 
eg : setTimeout(fn,0);

Comment: Do you use event onkeypress? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: If the function is being called with the right inputs then it's `if (this.x - scl != this.tail[this.tail.length-1].x)` that's causing the problem. Have a look at this logic and add some more detail to the question

Answer (score 1):

i "solved" it. 
I misunderstood what wasnt working for me.

```
`if (this.x - scl != this.tail[this.tail.length-1].x) {`
```

this if line is messing up my code. Everything works as expected.

Cant delete the question, thanks for the quick answers